# What is going to happen to me in Doha or Vienna Airport given the Coronavirus situation?

Tags: health, austria, qatar-airways, vienna, covid-19

I live in Iran and I have bought this Qatar Airways flight from Tehran (Iran) to Vienna for February 29. As far as I know, to this moment the flight is not cancelled for health concerns regarding Coronavirus. Although I don't know of any way to make sure about that. So I might have to go to airport and see what is going on.

And I don't want to cancel the flight, since I should be there in Vienna for my job starting March 1.

But, in case the flight is not cancelled by the airline, I don't know what is going to happen to me at the airports. Some people say that they might put me in quarantine at Qatar airport or at Vienna airport, maybe for 14 days.

Has anyone have any view or experience regarding such conditions? I am kind of panicked and overwhelmed by thoughts and concerns.

Comment: Why do you think you might be quarrantined? Have you recently been in China?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica No but Iran's number of affected is quite high too.

Comment: @Learner Have you contacted your employer?

Comment: Thnanks. I've not heard of any boarding bans or quarantine orders related to Iran. Has anyone else?

Comment: @Traveller Not yet, as I am not sure about what is going to happen.

Comment: @Learner If your employer is Vienna-based, they may know what the current local situation is (or indeed, their own HR policy on this), and be able to advise you? Do you live in or have visited any of the affected areas in Iran? In Doha, it seems you can expect to be screened https://www.thepeninsulaqatar.com/article/24/02/2020/Health-ministry-declares-additional-measures-on-coronavirus

Comment: @Traveller No, I don't live in and have not visited any affected areas in Iran.

Comment: Note that 2 of the 3 Tehran-Doha flights on Saturday have been cancelled, and the other one (which I suppose is the one you are booked on, given the schedule of the flight to Vienna) has been rescheduled to depart at 3:40, which is over an hour earlier than original planned. They probably budget for additional time for screening and aircraft disinfection, you should probably add a wide margin for any additional checks before departure they may add.

Answer (score 5):

You have to transit in Doha, Qatar. According to IATA

> QATAR - published 26.02.2020
>
> Passengers who have been in China (People's Rep.), Iran, Japan, Korea
>   (Rep.) or Singapore in the past 14 days will be required to
>   self-quarantine for 14 days.

https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm

Although the rule doesn't specify about transit, there is a chance that you will be denied boarding. You need to contact Qatar airlines to make sure.

Austria doesn't deny entry to passengers from Iran, as of now. Although unlikely, it can change from now to your travel date.

Comment: AFAIK Timatic is not showing the coronavirus information for airside transits.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes. Better to confirm.

Comment: If Qatar Airways was denying boarding to all pax from Iran, they would have to cancel all flights to Iran.  They haven't (yet), so they aren't.

Comment: @lambshaanxy They won't usually stop completely at first. They need their citizens and residents to return if needed. For instance, there are still direct flights from china to Singapore, even though the incoming passengers (residents of SG) will be quarantined for 14 days.

Answer (score 5):

The first thing you should do is contact your new employer. They may have procedures in place for any people coming for affected zones (China, Northern Italy, Iran...) to be isolated from other staff and/or the public.

It is difficult to guess what measures will be taken by the various authorities in Iran, Qatar and Austria regarding quarantine and isolation, or even outright travel bans, as **this can change by the hour**.

[Qatar Airways have already **cancelled 2 out of 3 of the flights from Tehran to Doha** these last few days](https://flightaware.com/live/findflight?origin=OIIE&destination=OTHH), and in the [upcoming days](https://fs.qatarairways.com/flightstatus/search?valueselected=froute&Statusfrom=Tehran%20(IKA)&StatusTo=Doha%20(DOH)&status_date=29%2F02%2F2020&lang=EN).

Even if there are no bans or quarantines, and even taking into account switching to a larger plane and cancellations/rebookings, **squeezing passengers booked on 3 different flights on a single probably means severe overbooking**. Be prepared to be bumped off the flight if there are Qatari citizens or residents and/or premium passengers that need a seat on that plane.

[The remaining flight on Saturday has been rescheduled to over an hour earlier](https://fs.qatarairways.com/flightstatus/search?valueselected=froute&Statusfrom=Tehran%20(IKA)&StatusTo=Doha%20(DOH)&status_date=29%2F02%2F2020&lang=EN). Add to that there will probably be lots of additional checks before boarding, and the fact that there will be overbooking, and you should be at the airport a LOT earlier that you would normally have, probably before midnight. You want to be the first in the queue. If online/mobile check-in is possible, do it as soon as it opens. You want your boarding pass to show "SEQ 001".

I suppose the rescheduling is to account for additional checks on arrival (as well as thorough disinfection of the aircraft after the flight) in order not to have issues with short connections.

[Current Qatar Airways procedures for flights from Iran](https://qatarairways.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006094697-Flights-from-Iran-and-South-Korea):

> In line with various global and local health warnings, all incoming passengers from Iran and South Korea **whose final destination is Doha and are showing no symptoms** of the Novel Coronavirus will be asked to stay in **home isolation or a quarantine facility for 14 days**.
>
> Passengers arriving from those countries who are **showing symptoms will be transferred to the Communicable Disease Centre** at the Hamad Medical Corporation.

So if you do not show any symptoms and are only in transit, you should have no issue boarding the flight to Vienna, unless Austria implements bans or quarantines by then.

Good luck!

Comment: According to the link, my flight (QR499) in cancelled now. ): Thank you very much!

Comment: So should I take that as a fixed cancellation, or it might be updated again, or be changed to another date? -- The remaining of hope in me!

Comment: @Learner They have cancelled 2 out of 3 flights for several days. Even though it could still change, I think it's quite unlikely for Saturday. It's impossible to book any IKA-DOH flight until March 14th, that should give you an idea of their anticipations.

Comment: @Learner You should probably try to call Qatar Airways. I suppose they will tell you your flight is cancelled, you can cancel or rebook your ticket, but I wonder what date they will be able to give you, probably no availabilities for several days at least.

Comment: I just received an email saying that my flight is rescheduled. I don't know what is going on. The problem with calling them is that they don't respond. I tried that several times.

Comment: Received email: We would like to inform you that there has been a change to the original flight timings in your itinerary. Please go to Manage My Booking to check the revised timings and confirm the changes.

Comment: But in Manage My Booking the timing is not revised but the same as before. There I only can see that the flight status is "Not confirmed".